# fabricJS - passing additional data or getting id from fabric.loadSVGFromString

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I have an array of objects I want to render. I want to pass additional data to SVG parser, so I can display title on hover etc.. - identyfy svg object in general. My code:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < response.data.items.length; i++) {

    var currItem = response.data.items[i];      
    fabric.loadSVGFromString(currItem.content, function(objects, options) {
        var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
        obj.tooltip = currItem.tooltip;
        canvas.add(obj);
        canvas.moveTo(obj, 3);
        canvas.calcOffset();
        canvas.renderAll();
    });

}
```

As loadSVGFromString is asynchronized (I suppose), data in currItem changes faster, resulting in invalid tooltip value.

I need a solution so I could identify created object and link it with data in any way (getting id from svgObject or passing data to parser)

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

please give a try to the `enlivenObjects()` function , like so (a snipet from my web application), Here i get my objects from db (svg & custom objects) and add them one by one on canvas:

```
 result.data.forEach(function (object) {
                                var tmpObject = JSON.parse(object.table_data);
                                console.log("obj id:",tmpObject.objectId);
                                fabric.util.enlivenObjects([tmpObject], function (objects) {
                                    var origRenderOnAddRemove = canvas.renderOnAddRemove;
                                    canvas.renderOnAddRemove = false;
                                    console.log(objects);
                                    objects.forEach(function (o) {
                                        //custom objects & svgobjects go to background
                                        if (o.typeTable == 'svgObject' || o.typeTable == 'customText' || o.typeTable == 'customRect' || o.typeTable == 'customCircle' || o.typeTable == 'customPolygon' || o.typeTable == 'customLine') {
                                            canvas.add(o);
                                            canvas.sendToBack(o);//send svg στο background
                                        } else {
                                            canvas.add(o);
                                        }
                                        //console.log(o);
                                    });

                                    canvas.renderOnAddRemove = origRenderOnAddRemove;
                                    canvas.renderAll();
                                });
                            });
```

Comment: Looks promising, but could you post example of your JSON?

Comment: It is very large json, especially the svg objects, but i will try to trim some character...

Comment: Well, i created a plunkr project(it doesnt do anything), you can open the 'objects.json' to see the objects that i bring from database: https://plnkr.co/edit/lcxiBJvVGiWgRjzXzqjs?p=info.   You can check the json with an online parser like this:  http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/